# breeze-sequelize - warning sequelize version is out of date 3.x has a critical security fix

Tags: javascript, node.js, breeze

I just added breeze-sequelize via npm. I got a warning to the effect of:

"Your sequelize version (breeze-sequelize has a dependency on sequelize) is out of date (has version 2.x). sequelize version 3.x has a critical security fix."

Has anyone run into this or any information related to this? Is breeze-sequelize still maintained. Looking for advice regarding this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are planning to update to the latest sequelize "soon". Hopefully next month.